# How to convert hex string into hex number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

Let's say I have string like this: `"0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819"`. I'd like to convert it into a number like this `0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819`.

```
> typeof "0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819"
"string"
> typeof 0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819
"number"
```

Comment: You do know that number is larger than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and loses a lot of precision, right? Are you sure you want to do this? Are you using a large integer module?

Comment: `parseInt( "0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819" )`

Comment: Also there is no such thing as a hex number.

Comment: Just found it out while ago, thanks. I was especially looking for solution that passes `typeof == "number"`, because of library I wanted to use, but losing precision is a problem. I'll need to solve a problem differently.